# share username with keychain between two application

Tags: flutter, keychain

for sharing the data from keychain is there any specific plugin for getting the data from native keychain like if we are saving username in **x application** in **keychain** so is there any plugin or dependency which can help us to get username data from x application to y application?
i tried **shared_preference_app_group** but it is not giving expected result.
i just want to access username which is saved in keychain in x app, i want to use that username in y application.